# CallCenter crashes the app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a huge issue with the CTCallCenter where the phone crashes if you get a call but never asnwers. Then the music should come back but instead evertyhing just dies.

This is what the code looks like:

```
_callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
_callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call){

    if (call.callState == CTCallStateDialing || call.callState==CTCallStateIncoming) { 
        _shouldResumeSongIfConnectionIsAlive=NO;

        if([[TFAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer] status]==TFAudioPlayerStatusPlaying){
            [[TFAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer] pause];
            isAppWasPlaying=YES;

        }else isAppWasPlaying=NO;

    }else if(call.callState==CTCallStateDisconnected){

        if(isAppWasPlaying){
            [[TFAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer] playForcedFromWhereItStopped];
            _shouldResumeSongIfConnectionIsAlive=YES;
        }
    }
};
```

I cannot find any way to handle the case where the user doesnt pick up their phone. The CTCallCenter only has Incoming, Disconnect, Connect and Dialing from what I could see.

Does anyone have a clue?

Edit:

This issue only appears when I run the app on the phone when its NOT connected and debugging. The app dies directly when the other person hangs up (missed call).

Stacktrace:

```
Date/Time:       2012-11-19 14:20:47.470 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B179)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbbadbeef
Crashed Thread:  10

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x356bb004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x356bb1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x372203ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3721f0ea __CFRunLoopRun + 818
4   CoreFoundation                  0x371a249e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x371a2366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   GraphicsServices                0x320af432 GSEventRunModal + 130
7   UIKit                           0x33926e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
8   My App                          0x0001e63c 0x1a000 + 17980
9   My App                          0x0001c268 0x1a000 + 8808
```

Also! If I run the app with DEPLOY POSTPROCESSING = YES it doesnt crash. I dont get it